# YAML parser yq modifying file in place with filter

Tags: yaml, yq

### background

I prepare a manifest file of Kubernetes, build a docker image from circleci in GitOps operation, push it to ECR, and at the same time, send PR of image tag change from circleci to GitHub

At that time, I tried to edit the manifest file in the circleci job as well

### Problems, unknown points

I tried to change the yaml file using yq command.

```
yq -y -i  '.images |= map(select(.name=="XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/backend-admin").newTag |= '$CIRCLE_SHA1')'  k8s/overlays/dev/bases/kustomization.yaml
```

manifest file

```
namespace: production

bases:
  - ../../../bases/admin

patchesStrategicMerge:
  - patch-admin.yaml

images:
  - name: nginx
    newTag: 1.15.2
  - name: XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/backend
    newName: XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/backend
    newTag: backend-tag
  - name: XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/frontend
    newName: XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/frontend
    newTag: latest
```

but error occur

```
jq: error: a99cce09747507feb74799e1e1c9459aba43d4a6/0 is not defined at <top-level>, line 1:
.images |= map(select(.name=="XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/backend-admin").newTag |= a99cce09747507feb74799e1e1c9459aba43d4a6)
```

I think that the cause is that it is included up to
I saw various articles, but none of them led to a solution.

I want to know if anyone knows something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The filter generated is right, but the update operator `|=` on the RHS takes either a string type or a proper object type to be present. What you have is not interpreted as a literal string. Put the tag around quotes `".."`

```
yq -y '.images |= map(select(.name=="XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/backend").newTag |= "a99cce09747507feb74799e1e1c9459aba43d4a6")'
```

Also `yq` like its predecessor `jq` supports passing argument fields to be used within the filter, so you can do

```
yq -y --arg tag "${CIRCLE_SHA1}" '.images |= map(select(.name=="XXXXXXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.ap-northeast-1.amazonaws.com/backend").newTag |= $tag )'
```

Comment: Oh, this is easier to see. Thank you！！

Answer (score 0):

Variables are not expanded inside single quotes. Please go outside.

```
'$CIRCLE_SHA1' 

to

"'$CIRCLE_SHA1'"
```

Comment: You can pass in args to `yq` like `--arg tag "${CIRCLE_SHA1}"` like I've shown in my answer

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it